# ¿Cómo usar un botón en shiny que al darle genere una tabla?

Tags: r, botón, shiny

Estoy creando una aplicación shiny en la que quiero que al darle al botón "go", se genere una tabla con un csv que he cargado y una columna que añado. He probado el siguiente código pero el botón no hace nada:

```
a2 <- read.csv("especie.csv")

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "go"),

  hr(),
  dataTableOutput("tabla")
)

server <- function(input, output){


  observeEvent(input$go, {
    data <- a2%>%cbind(Plate_Source=c("Sample"))
  })



  output$tabla <- renderDataTable({(data)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que `data` se define en el entorno del `observeEvent` y no puede ser utilizada luego en el entorno definido por `renderDataTable`. En shiny para pasar variables de un entorno a otro tienes que usar la reactividad, es decir debes definir un objeto reactivo para tu variable `data`.

Una forma de hacerlo es la siguiente (use el conjunto iris solo para el ejemplo y tuve que cargar `dplyr` para usar el `%>%`):

```
a2 <- iris

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "go"),

  hr(),
  dataTableOutput("tabla")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  rv <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    rv$data <- a2%>%cbind(Plate_Source=c("Sample"))
  })



  output$tabla <- renderDataTable({
    rv$data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

También se puede introducir el `renderDataTable` dentro del entorno reactivo del `observeEvent`, como sigue:

```
a2 <- iris

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "go"),

  hr(),
  dataTableOutput("tabla")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  rv <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    data <- a2%>%cbind(Plate_Source=c("Sample"))

     output$tabla <- renderDataTable({
        data
        })
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Te recomiendo leer este [articulo](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/understanding-reactivity.html) para entender mejor la reactividad.